# The operator \boxtimes and \boxplus in automorphic representations

Tags: automorphic-forms, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations, nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures

Given two automorphic representations $\pi_1, \pi_2$ of $GL_2(\mathbb A_Q)$ and $GL_3(\mathbb A_Q)$ respectively. Let $\pi_i =\otimes_v \pi_{i, v}$.

Now, for each $v$, let $\pi_{1, v}\boxtimes \pi_{2, v}$ and $\pi_{1, v}\boxplus \pi_{2, v}$ be the admissible representation of $GL_6(Q_v)$, which, via local Langlands, corresponds tensor product and direct sum of the Weil-Deligne representations.

My question is, are there explicit construction of the $\boxtimes$ and $\boxplus$ operators?

In fact, is there any basic introduction to these operators? I see them quite a lot, but have not found any explanatory definitions...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean here? The exterior tensor product $\boxtimes$ is a priori a rep of $GL(2) \times GL(3)$. It is rather trivial, that it will remain automorphic. What is $\boxplus$?

Comment: boxtimes. You may like to see the paper by Langlands "einmaerchen" paper in Corvallis where these operations were discussed for the first time.

Comment: Sorry; the sentence got mangled. I meant the paper titled "...., Einmarchen" by Langlands, in the Corvallis volume on automorphic forms, Shimura Varieties, L functions". This introduces the operations which you have mentioned.  

Comment: Here is the link to the "Ein Maerchen" paper:
 http://sunsite.ubc.ca/DigitalMathArchive/Langlands/pdf/autoreps-ps.pdf

Comment: @Aakumadula: okay, thx for the explanation. $\boxtimes$ is not the exterior tensor.

Comment: Okay, this is locally the unique subquotient of the parabolic induced one.